# Ubuntu 20.04 on SSD: Filesystem?

Tags: filesystem, ssd

I have a Crucial BX500 SSD, 960 GB in dual boot with Windows 10 Update 04/2020 and Ubuntu 20.04.1. The disk is in GPT, the EFI partition is fat32 and the rest of Windows, of course, NTFS. On Linux, I only use root and home (since I have 16GB of RAM and AMD graphics card with 4GB), both are in Ext4. That said, come and ask, for those who have a deeper knowledge about file systems, which one should I use. This is because I'm thinking of leaving the entire SSD for Ubuntu (and putting win10 on a VM). What would you recommend: BTRFS, XFS, EXT4? Which would give better performance on the SSD and would be more secure. (I remember that OpenSuSE used Btrfs on the root partition and XFS on the home). Ubuntu 20.04 suggests, at the time of a clean installation, to use XFS in Root, but points out that it is experimental. What's up? Any personal tips?

Answer (score 2):

It is really opinion and usage based, but my 2 cents are below:

- I'm writing this answer from laptop with SSD where Ubuntu is installed into *ext4* (GPT, two partitions for `/` and `/home`). Having no filesystem related issues since 2013.
- Recently I have installed SSD to other laptop for Ubuntu testing and partitioned it using *btrfs*. This adds fantastic features - backup and restore the filesystem snapshots by using [TimeShift](https://teejeetech.in/timeshift/). This functionality is great if you need to use real hardware with snapshots like if it was VirtualMachine with snapshots.

So you have to decide by yourself what do you need.

Comment: I agree. Ext4 is the default, and the "safe" choice, BTRFS and XFS adds more options, but is a bit more experimental still. As I understand it, XFS is better at handling high I/O loads, while BTRFS has features that compare to ZFS with snapshots etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same question (except with installing Mint 20.1, but that shouldn't make any real difference, I suppose). Laptop with only one drive bay, which is SSD. I was told that Ext4 uses journalling, to help prevent data loss in case of power interruption - which is good. But that, because of this, Ext4 writes journal information, and that it not only does this with every file write, it also does it to every file that is READ. He said that this might cause the drive to fail appreciably sooner, because it would mean that it will be getting written to *much* more often than just each time I download or save a new file to it, or install updates from my distro's update manager. However, he confessed to not knowing enough to be able to suggest a better file system type for a single-drive SSD linux installation. My SSD is one that has been sold for several years and has always been one of the cheapest ones available, so it might not have "longevity features" or even very durable memory, and buying any kind of computer-related item is likely to be impossible for the foreseeable future (otherwise, I would spend $15 on a power port that is less touchy and try to install it, or at least a cheap battery that would take a charge - as even a cheap Chinese battery would stop the laptop from instant-off every time the wind or the cat touches the power cable). Therefore, I would happily give up fastest speed for longest life. Laptop is six or seven years old, has an i5 3210M with six gigabytes of RAM and a simple BIOS menu with relatively few options, but it seems to still function okay, and I can not replace it.